Jitters in bones of armature in fbx export but can't see those jitters in blender
I have made an animation where a cricket player stances for the ball, so everything looks fine in the blender scene but whenever i try to export the character with animations, i can see jitters or random movement in the legs of character in the fbx and same in unity scene which i cant see in the blender scene.
here is the scene of blender- https://youtu.be/oDLmjJtQZcM
here is the scene of fbx review- https://youtu.be/NjFW-FGh6QY
I tried fixing the keyframes for the bones and also i tried shifting to blender 3.6 from blender 4.1 as i thought it could be a bug, but whenever i try to open this project in 3.6, i cant even see the armature but just the character

Try baking in the target framerate before export

can you explain it in detail?

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
